# What is the purpose of the various types added by zlib and how can I use them?

Tags: c++, c, zlib, binary-data

I am currently trying, with the goal of learning the basic usage of zlib, to create a small utility to compress and decompress files in C++. I am using the `compress2` and `uncompress` functions provided by zlib to facilitate this. Both of these functions, however, take various types that seem specific to zlib (`Bytef`, `uLongf`, etc.) without any automatic conversions between them and C++ types (or, rather, the pointers to each of these types). This makes simple code to interface with zlib more complex, unless I write my entire application based around zlib's types.

My question has 3 parts:

- What is the purpose of these types as opposed to built-in types such as `unsigned long`, which I am using in my own file I/O code to represent file lengths?
- What is the proper way to use these types? Can I reinterpret cast my `char` pointers to data to (de)compress to `Bytef` pointers without changing the data length from the length of my char array? Because `char` is one byte and `Bytef`'s name suggests  that it is the same length, I imagine that I can, but I want to make sure. Can I simply assign an `unsigned long` (or other non-zlib integral type) to `uLongf` and other zlib seemingly-integral types?
- Where is zlib's official documentation on these types?

I skimmed the [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html) and fully read the sections that could possibly seem relevant, along with a ctrl+f aided search, to no avail. My search engine also does not know the answer.

Comment: You say there is no automatic conversion to C++ types, but from my recollection for example `Bytef` is a type alias for an `unsigned char`. Are you sure?

Comment: (I expect the aliases exist in order to provide a common suite of type names across language bindings.)

Comment: Admittedly the manual seems lax in this regard but it should be clear from the actual headers.

Comment: I have no trouble using standard types with zlib. They are just typedefs in zconf.h.

Comment: You mention `unsigned long` - which is 32 or 64 bits depending on which compiler you use.

Comment: The correct type for file sizes is `off_t`, but even then you *still* have to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` on 32-bit platforms.

Comment: All of zlib's types seem to be typedefs to various built-in types, but I am using slightly different types than what zlib prefers (ie. `char*` rather than `unsigned char*`), which makes pointers that zlib's functions use incompatible with my own. The zconf.h header tells me what they are typedef'd to, but the typedef suggests that I am expected to use them somehow differently than I would the built-in types (otherwise, why bother making them look like separate types?). The comments here seem to suggest the opposite, however. Is there any official documentation to back this up?

Comment: The `f` stands for "far pointer" from the 16-bit segmented era - which had different syntax on different compilers, thus the abstraction. Nowadays it's just defined as a regular pointer.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a library to use some sort of configuration in order to be portable on systems where types are inherently different or need to be specified differently.  This is rarely documented specifically in my experience as it's generally a non-issue. You may be reading complexity into this that isn't there.

Comment: It's common to implement a thin "glue" layer that adapts application data to the contract of the library. The trick is to do this efficiently. Casting from unsigned to signed char would be done in the glue so you can ignore it otherwise. Char vs. unsigned char is an interesting example. On nearly all architectures a cast of an array of one to the other, will "just work," with the compiler generating no code. But C++ doesn't guarantee this, so special handling may be required for some. The glue layer consolidates this messiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For portability, your file lengths should use `off_t`, not `unsigned long`. On some systems those are different sizes, with `off_t` being longer.
- Yes, you can just cast between `Bytef` and `char`. (`Bytef` is actually `unsigned char`, but there is no conversion required.) `uLong` is simply `unsigned long`. (See zconf.h.)
- zlib's documentation is zlib.h, where those types are called out as parameters of the functions. You can use `zlibCompileFlags()` to determine the number of bits in each type. (See zlib.h.)